# Python3: User defined version of Optional type, how to extend the Union type

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I have a class, let's call it `Foo`, and I would like to be able to use a `Fooable` type that signals that a value may be any union of a given list of types or an instance of the `Foo` class.

This is quite similar to the `Optional` type but with `Foo` instead of `None`.

Here's an example of the type

```py
class Foo:
    pass

# ... some sort of type definition ...


# Equivalent to Union[Foo, int, str]
x: Fooable[int, str] = 2
```

I know that for Python >= 3.10 you can solve this quite easily with the `|` typing operator, but let's assume that's not an option.

This also kind of works, but only for one type:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union


class Foo:
    pass


G = TypeVar("G")

Fooable = Union[G, Foo]


# this works
x: Fooable[int] = 3

# this does not
y: Fooable[int, str] = 3
# TypeError: Too many parameters for typing.Union[~G, Foo]; actual 2, expected 1
```

I'm hoping there's a way to allow any number of types

Comment: I'm trying really, really hard to think of a reason you'd *want* to do that...can you give more context? Any code that uses that type is going to have a lot of checks to narrow it...

Comment: The use-case is with an ORM, pydantic and Null. For how we do updates/insert functions for the database: if a value in the given pydantic model is `None`, it doesn't get updated, if it is `Null` it will be updated to `null` in the database. Having a `Nullable` type similar to `Optional` would be very nice.

Comment: So you need a trinary instead of binary logical union. Got it. I would use a [sentinel object](https://python-patterns.guide/python/sentinel-object/#the-null-object-pattern) to indicate the null case then.

Comment: Yup! We're using an instance of a `Null` class as a sentinel object. Now it's the type hint that we're trying to figure out, which leads us back to the question above: How would you go about making a `Nullable` type that allows a property to be either `None`, `Null`, or any other subscripted type